# Calculate all user activities in percentage for donut chart

Tags: math, percentage

**Description:**

An Example:

1. I have a forum with 250 users.
2. Users can perform certain actions like posting a picture or status, commenting on a post, up voting etc
3. now I want to calculate the percentage of each activity being done from those 250 users

e.g posts = 20%;

comments = 30%;

Now I am looking for an equation to do this!!

that tells me that my forum is 20% used for posting 30% is used for chatting etc so that afterwards I can compare the highest percentage out of 100.

I am a bit weak in math. Can any one help me?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all it doesn't matter how many users you have. You can ignore that number.

The general "equation" for calculating percentage looks as follows:

```
part       %   
-----  =  ---
whole     100
```

or equivalently:

```
          part
% = 100 * -----
          whole
```

In your case "whole" corresponds to the total number of activities (`<number of posts>` + `<number of comments>` + `<number of ...>`) so your "equations" become:

```
<% of posts>    = 100 * <number of posts>    / <number of activities>
<% of comments> = 100 * <number of comments> / <number of activities>
<% of ...>      = 100 * <number of ...>      / <number of activities>
```

**Example:** If you have 200 comments, and the total number of activities is 500 then the percentage of comments would be

```
100 * 200 / 500 = 40
```

In other words, with 200 comments and 500 activities you'd have 40% comments.